# How to implement Firebase in Xamarin Forms UWP

Tags: firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, uwp

I already implemented firebase to my xamarin forms Android,iOS project,but UWP not uses firebase,so how to deal with push notification on UWP beside firebase.

Their are lots of process to handle push notification using WNS,but Is it possible to maintain firebase and WNS in Xamarin Forms? Because I am using firebase payloads to share information with devices,but how to manage this in UWP?

Comment: Try [chillcat](https://example-code.com/csharp_winrt/fireBase.asp) library

Comment: Receiving firebase notification not found on this library.

Comment: firebase doesnt have SDK for UWP. You can ask firebase support if they have any